# How many environments are set when running pre-commit install?

Tags: pre-commit, pre-commit.com

While running `pre-commit install`, I wondered if each non-local hook has its own environment or if there is just one environment for all of them.

```
$ pre-commit run --all-files
[INFO] Initializing environment for https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks.
[INFO] Initializing environment for https://github.com/psf/black.
[INFO] Installing environment for https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks.
[INFO] Once installed this environment will be reused.
[INFO] This may take a few minutes...
[INFO] Installing environment for https://github.com/psf/black.
[INFO] Once installed this environment will be reused.
[INFO] This may take a few minutes...
```

For this particular case, is the environment for `pre-commit-hooks` the same environment for `black`, or are they different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

they are all separate and isolated from each other, which is shown in the output:

```
[INFO] Installing environment for https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks.
...
[INFO] Installing environment for https://github.com/psf/black.
...
```

also [from the docs](https://pre-commit.com/#pre-commit-install-hooks):

> Each hook is initialized in a separate environment appropriate to the language the hook is written in

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit